# Progress - Monitor Database Read & Writes

Tags: performance, monitoring, analysis, openedge, progress-db

I'm new to all this and would like some guidance and I'm not sure if this is the correct place, any help would be appreciated and really aimed at someone who doesn't know what they're doing, not my job role but I'm being asked to pick it up.

We have a customer server running our Progress application, the last few days the server has been experiencing extreme performance issues, crippling the performance for all other users.

We know it's being caused by our application, as we can see it writing out to the Progress app server log, unfortunately we can't pinpoint the root cause.

I've been asked to monitor the database and see which tables are being hit to get a further understanding.

I've had a look and can only see third party monitoring solutions.

My question is, is there a native Progress monitoring tool and how would one roughly go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The native OpenEdge monitoring tool is PROMON. This is included with every installation. Just open up a proenv window and type:

```
proenv> promon /path/to/db/dbname
```

Most of the interesting stuff is under the R&D menu.

"OpenEdge Management" is sometimes considered a monitoring tool but it is an add-on product and is mostly focused on management and administration.

There are also (freemium) 3rd party tools focused on monitoring such as ProTop http://wss.com/protop (full disclosure, that's my product).

Or you can "roll your own" monitoring using the built-in virtual system tables.